# Conversion error while using ',' in STUFF - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query:

```
select STUFF((SELECT ',' + rr1._cv_id 
FROM #reportrows rr1 
WHERE rr1._c_id=rr._c_id 
FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1,null)FROM #reportrows rr
```

In this query, _cv_id is integer type. Upon running this query I get to see below error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.
```

Any help?!

Answer (score 5):

The id is not a string, so convert it:

```
SELECT STUFF( (SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), rr1._cv_id)
. . .
```

Comment: `varchar(MAX)` is probably overkill here (if `rr1._cv_id` is an `int` then this only needs to be at most a `varchar(11)`, as that can handle every possible value).

Answer (score 4):

looks like the column cv_id is of numeric data type. therefore you need to convert to string before concatenate with comma

```
select STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(10), rr1._cv_id)
FROM #reportrows rr1 
WHERE rr1._c_id=rr._c_id 
FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1,null) FROM #reportrows rr
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert `rr1._cv_id` to string

```
select STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(rr1._cv_id AS VARCHAR(20))
FROM #reportrows rr1 
WHERE rr1._c_id=rr._c_id 
FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1,null)FROM #reportrows rr
```